# My data is wiped out after a battery service

Tags: battery, nexus-7, tablet

I hit my Nexus 7 with Android 4.2 on it, into a glass bottle. Somehow, internally the battery got disconnected so it didn't turn on. It was only flickering a black screen when attached to a power cord. I didn't want to fix it myself so I brought it to a certified service for mobile devices. I received it back but it had installed Android 4.4 and all of the data was wiped out.

What did the people from the service do to my Nexus 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but they did factory reset to it. Probably it is that bad when the battery detaches from the other part of the device :) 
Don't they make these devices crash proof? I just hit it into a glass bottle :D

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like they just replaced the device and gave you a new/refurbished one. Your original device will be fixed (if possible), and then it will be wiped and turned into a refurbished unit.

If you didn't back up any of your data, it is gone. Hopefully you did; I'm pretty sure anytime you send in a device for service, they warn you that it could be completely wiped.

Comment: Well they didn't tell me that they will wipe out the data, but I can tell that it is the same device because of the sticker with the serial number on the back. It doesn't seem removed and then sticked again.

Comment: As if they just made factory reset and updated it to Android 4.4 :D luckily I don't do my job with my nexus. I had couple of books on my kindle and some videos. But I can replace them. Your google account keeps track what apps were installed. So when I logged in it started downloding them.

Comment: There is SSN which is the serial number on the back cover and on the box, and there is CSSN which is the number in Android tablet info serial number. They match so it is the same tablet.